# Que veut dire l'expression « Autant en emporte le vent » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, sens, expressions

L'expression « *Autant en emporte le vent* » est la traduction du titre du célèbre film « *Gone with the wind* ».

Bien que le titre anglais soit plutôt simple à comprendre, la traduction français me laisse dubitative sur son sens. Qui emporte le vent ? Autant ? Cette expression a-t-elle un sens et d'où vient-elle ?

Comment: Et dans le sud de la France, on pourrait dire "Autant en emporte le vent d'Autan", ce qui rend vraiment fou. :)

Comment: @biozic - D'habitude quand [le journal régional](http://www.ladepeche.fr/article/2012/10/23/1471498-fenouillet-autan-en-a-emporte-le-vent.html) veut faire un bon mot pour évoquer une période d'Autan particulièrement forte, il titre _Autan en emporte le vent_.

Comment: @biozic Oui, c'est bien connu. *Le vent qui vient à travers la montagne m'a rendu fou...* (Hugo)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

« Autant en emporte le vent » est un ancien proverbe français. Comme beaucoup de proverbes, sa construction syntaxique est inhabituelle pour des oreilles modernes.
C'est une expression figée : [après « autant en emporte »](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=autant+en+emporte%2Cautant+en+emporte+le+vent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cautant%20en%20emporte%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cautant%20en%20emporte%20le%20vent%3B%2Cc0), c'est quasiment toujours « le vent » qui vient.
 Le film est suffisamment célèbre pour avoir fait oublier le proverbe.

Le [*Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/emporter) explique le proverbe ainsi :

> Fig., Autant en emporte le vent, se dit en parlant de Promesses auxquelles on n'ajoute pas foi, ou de Menaces dont les effets ne sont point à craindre. Il me promet monts et merveilles, autant en emporte le vent.

Grammaticalement, il y a une inversion du sujet : « le vent en emporte autant ». Le pronom *en* désigne les promesses ou menaces : elles sont tellement légères que le vent peut les emporter — plus précisément, le vent emporte des choses équivalentes.

Comment: En somme, l'expression aurait un sens voisin de cette autre plus moderne et assez répandue : *"Les paroles s'envolent[, les écrits restent]."*

Answer (score 4):

Le traducteur du roman de Margaret Mitchell  *Gone with the wind*<sup>1</sup> (dont le film est une adaptation) a choisi de prendre une expression française qui existait déjà et contenant à la fois le mot vent (pour *wind*) et l'idée de disparition, d'oubli (pour *gone*).

Le *Dictionnaire Historique de la langue française*<sup>2</sup> signale l'emploi de l'expression sous la forme « autant en porte le vent » dès le 13ème siècle pour dire  « cela n'a pas d'importance ».

Dans cette expression **autant** est employé pour exprimer une quantité (comme dans l'expression *Je gagne autant par mois* ([qui est semble-t-il un belgicisme](http://www.ateliertheatrejeanvilar.be/files/spectacle/65.pdf)) de quelque chose qui est sous-entendu (les mauvais coups du sort).

**Vent** est à prendre ici au sens métaphorique, sens qu'il avait dès le moyen-âge, le mot désignant les influences du sort, qui telles le vent qui déplace les objets, font disparaître les mauvais moments. On a aussi employé à la même époque le mot vent pour désigner l'influence d'un milieu, (voir les expressions : « le vent du peuple », « le vent de la cour ».

Ce que je ne sais pas c'est si l'expression *autant en emporte le vent* était utilisée pour rendre *gone with the wind* avant que le traducteur du roman de Margaret Mitchell s'en empare.

<sup>1</sup> : L'expression *gone with the wind* existait d'ailleurs avant que Margaret Mitchell en fasse un titre de roman, même si c'est grâce à ce roman qu'elle est passée dans le langage courant en anglais. [1810](http://books.google.fr/books?id=PbMRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA287&dq=%22gone%20with%20the%20wind%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=2ZmMUpOsBu7A7AaP54GwBg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22gone%20with%20the%20wind%22&f=false) ; [1833](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Bd0XAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA330&dq=%22gone%20with%20the%20wind%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=nZiMUovnF86AhAef-ID4Dg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22gone%20with%20the%20wind%22&f=false)

<sup>2</sup> : sld Alain Rey, éditions Le Robert.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a inversion du sujet. C'est *le vent* qui emporte donc avec lui des choses semblables à ce à quoi il est fait allusion.

Answer (score 1):

Car, ou soit ly sains apostolles ,
D’aubes vestus, d’amys coeffez ,
Qui ne saint fors saintes estolles
Dont par le col prent ly mauffez
De mal talant tout eschauffez ,
Aussi bien meurt que cilz servans ,
De ceste vie cy bouffez :
AUTANT EN EMPORTE LY VENS.

Autre Ballade, Le Testament

Villon

Comment: C'est une bonne citation mais on cherche aussi de l'explication.  Voici le [tour] du site et le centre [help]. Bienvenue sur French language SE.